# how to link google drive folder to google CDN bucket folder?

Tags: directory, storage, cdn, bucket, drive

its seems that google devs are very primitive.
there is no way to do so.
also, I cannot upload any file OR folder from google drive to the bucket.
also, I cannot upload files OR folder from my android to the bucket.
any suggestions ?